# Connect Server to multiple clients

Tags: java, networking, client-server

I have created a client/server application. Now, clients can send requests to the server and receive server response. Now I want to notify all connected clients to perform some actions. How can I do that?

Comment: If the clients do not have a socket open for listening, you need to have a long-polling request from client to server for handling this.  Look how AJAX is implemented.

Comment: That is okay Andersen.. Now It is possible or not to send some request from server side to client.

Comment: If it's ok why are you asking him to repeat himself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register all connected clients on the server and store references to clients in the `List` instance.

If you want to inform your clients asynchronously then open ServerSocket instance on your every client and accept connections only from the server they are using.

And in this case your server acts as a client and sends a request to all connected clients like a client sends request to the server.